# Migrate existing date from chrome.storage.sync to chrome.storage.local

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Without properly understanding the differences between chrome.storage.sync and chrome.storage.local, i used sync storage in my chrome extension. The extension is live for almost 6 months with more than 10k users. Now I ran into the storage limit of 100KB in chrome.storage.sync. 
In the next update, i would like to update the storage to chrome.storage.local without affecting the existing users. 
How can I go about it?

Comment: what have you tried? (show code). seems simple just migrate it to local and delete each sync property.

Comment: but of course its much harder to migrate users that use your extension in more than one device. you would need to know when to delete sync and when to not overwrite something newer in local

Comment: test on update whether you **new** local.storage exist. If it does, then OK (this is for further updates). If it doesn't, fetch you storage.sync data and save it in storage.local.